# excecuting node js file via php

Tags: php, node.js

When I run the command `node auth.js` in my cmd tool,I get the output..I want to get the output of javascript in php file.So I tried below codes but its returning empty output

```
<?php
    exec("node auth.js &", $output);
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

I also tried full path.But still not working.And is it safe to use the above codes ? or is there any php class wrapper to do this job.

Comment: What does `var_dump($output)` produce?

Comment: Do you really want to background that process?

Answer (score -1):

I seems you are telling to the shell to send in background the executable (node and its file), so the standard output will be redirect on the new forked shell instead of the one you are waiting for in your php code.
If you want to leave the program executing in background, you can redirect output to a file and then read it inside php.

Hope it was useful to you :)

Comment: how to do that ? sorry i am new to this

Comment: Hello Andrea! As questionned in comments, it is a very good idea to explain how to do the things you mention in an answer; we value quality answers that stand by themselves: this means put the code which actually does `redirect output to a file and then read it inside php.`

Comment: `exec("node auth.js > /file_to_send_output_to &");` and the shell output will be written there

Comment: hey , i tried background exec("node auth.js > out.txt &");..file is created but its empty.